# Test AngularJS Provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am decorating AngularJS `$log` through a provider.

The decorator is working great, however I am really struggling with testing it.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ny8x/519/) that has my provider and my attempt at a test.

Any help on how to test this would be greatly appreciated, I am very new to testing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is a decorator for $http with a new abort function ...

```
function httpAbortDecorator($provide) {

$provide.decorator('$http', ["$delegate", "$q", function ($delegate, $q) {

  ...

  $delegate.abort = function (request) {
    var cancelerKey, canceler;
    cancelerKey = $delegate.getCancelerKey(request.method, request.url);
    canceler = $delegate.cancelerMap[cancelerKey];
    if (canceler != null) {
      if (request.timeout != null && typeof request.timeout !== "number") {
        canceler.resolve();
        delete $delegate.cancelerMap[cancelerKey];
      }
    }
  };

    return $delegate;
    }]);
}
```

then a unit test ...

```
it('should not abort a request if the request timeout is not set', function () {
  spyOn(http, 'abort').and.callThrough();
  var ABORT_URL = "/api/";
  var HTTP_METHOD = "GET";
  http.pendingRequests.push({url: ABORT_URL, method: "GET"});
  http.addCancelerKey(HTTP_METHOD, ABORT_URL);
  state.go("login");
  expect(http.abort.calls.count()).toBe(1);
  expect(Object.keys(http.cancelerMap).length).toBe(1);
});
```

hope this gives you some direction - its not the full code.